# How do I host a Django project on a host that already exists?

Tags: django, web, host

I have a project in Django and I have a host that was sent to me where my project should appear, but I do not know how I will do it. I uploaded the project folder with a Filezilla, but I do not know if it is possible to run the Django commands in SSH or SFTP. I've watched some related videos, but they all teach how to host them in Heroku and PythonAnyWhere, but I need to host it on my university website. What should I do?

Comment: Use google for this. Search how to deploy django project using apache/nginx. Post questions here if you get stuck anywhere

Comment: run sudo apt-get install "django-package-name" and it will just work! No, don't do it because it is joke. You have to be more concrete and provide more details. See also previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04 If you want to setup your project in a Linux server, this is a great tutorial to set up your Django project

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information out there on deploying Django, having walked through the path before it can be confusing. You need to determine the environment that you are going to be on.

You mentioned your "University website" and a "host" sent to you. Is this host a linux environment? a folder somewhere on a shared drive? a virtual machine that you have access to sftp or ftp? Will this be internal use only behind a firewall or live in a production environment?

Once you understand the environment then there are multiple routes you can go. apache/nginx was mentioned already.

Here are two links that can help you get ready. 
[MDN - Django Tutorial Part 11: Deploying Django to production](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment) 
 [Django docs - Deploying Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/)

Answer (score 0):

You HAVE TO CONFIGURE YOUR GIT AGAIN AND THEN PUSH THE FILES TO HEROKU :

1. `git init`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "new-commit"`
4. `git push Heroku master`

Then go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps and hover to your app setting there you would get an option for adding custom domain after adding your domain over there go to your c panel/DNS and add Heroku app link over there after this the custom domain will appear ho your Heroku app